# How to config WebStorm to run JS files?

Tags: javascript

I want to config WebStorm idle such that it can execute JS files just like Python idle which runs codes. There is already a predefined Node.js configuration which seems to work but in fact it doesn't. When I run JS files under the configuration, nothing is shown to the out put.

Here is how my situation seems :

[image]

Code running seems to work but nothing is shown. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/en/#download

dowload node Interpreter.
Click right button on your code field, choose **Run 'gg.js'**,
in field **Node Interpreter** enter path to *node.exe* file, the press *Ok*

More info:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html

Comment: It seems that the problem was with the Node installation itself. Because after I installed the latest version of Node by the link you provided, everything started to work without going into the details that you suggested. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yep, this solved my problem exactly! first day with js